# How to redefine a function in Mathematica by appending to it?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

When doing calculations in Mathematica I often need to redefine a function by appending to it. For example if I define

```
f[n_] := n^2 + n + 1
```

then after some time I'd like to add 2n^3 so from now on

```
f[n] = 2n^3 + n^2 + n + 1.
```

Then I'd like to add Sin[n] and going further

```
f[n] = 2n^3 + n^2 + n + 1 + Sin[n].
```

And so on.

It's easy to do with variables, for example x += 2. Is there something similar for functions?…

Edited to add – yes, I was doing that to semi-manually find a function that fits data the best. I know there are functions to do that but I wanted to see if I can get there myself. I  did that but the way was not elegant so that prompted this question.

Comment: It would really help to know what the criterion is that causes you to want to add a term. Is it that different definitions apply for different values of `n`?

Comment: @Verbeia It looks like the OP just tries to select a combination of base functions which is appropriate for fitting some experimental data within experimental errors. Probably it is a homework.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov  - true, but why mix up polynominal and trigonometric basis functions? I am a simple economist but it just looks odd to me.

Comment: @Verbeia If it is known that experimental data contain (or may contain) both periodical and non-periodical components, it is quite logical to use a combination of polynomial and trigonometric function for fitting.

Comment: @Alexey just in case you are still doing that by hand :) http://creativemachines.cornell.edu/eureqa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a list of your basis functions and then just pick up needed number of elements:

```
fList = {n^2, n, 1, 2 n^3, Sin[n]}; 

f[n_] = Total[Take[fList, 3]]
f[n_] = Total[Take[fList, 4]]
f[n_] = Total[Take[fList, 5]]
(*
=> 1 + n + n^2
=> 1 + n + n^2 + 2 n^3
=> 1 + n + n^2 + 2 n^3 + Sin[n]
*)
```

Comment: I think this works best for my needs, as I can append to the list if needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are many subtleties craving under your question. Monster subtleties, I mean.

I'll not enter the meander, but you may do something like:

```
f[n] = n^2;
f[n] = f[n] + 2
(* but for evaluation *)
f[n] /. n -> 2
```

So, for example for plotting this:

```
Plot[f[n] /. n -> x, {x, 0, 1}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
                                PlotLabel  -> Framed@f[n]]
```

[image]

However, you should NOT do this. Read more about [delayed definition!](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html)

Answer (score 3):

A late-to-the-party solution: the code below uses an auxiliary function, and to add a term for all subsequent uses, you just have to call a function once, with a second parameter being a pure function expressing the term you want to add:

```
ClearAll[f];
Module[{g},
 g[n_] := n^2 + n + 1;
 f[n_, add_: Automatic] /; add === Automatic := g[n];
 f[n_, add_: Automatic] := Block[{m}, g[m] = g[m] + add[m]; g[n]];
]
```

Examples of use:

```
In[43]:= f[m]
Out[43]= 1 + m + m^2

In[44]:= f[m, 2 #^3 &]
Out[44]= 1 + m + m^2 + 2 m^3

In[45]:= f[m]
Out[45]= 1 + m + m^2 + 2 m^3

In[46]:= f[m, Sin]
Out[46]= 1 + m + m^2 + 2 m^3 + Sin[m]

In[47]:= f[m]
Out[47]= 1 + m + m^2 + 2 m^3 + Sin[m]
```

With this approach, you should be careful though to call the two-argument form only once, when you want to add the term to the function - or it will be added every time you call.

Comment: +1, I'm not surprised that you came up with a simple, clever solution for this.

Comment: @rcollyer Took me a while. Actually, IMO this one is more a design problem. Thanks for the upvote.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends why you need to redefine your function `f`. If the reason is that you realised the previous definition was wrong, then by all means just go back to the cell in question, edit it and re-evaluate it to re-define `f`.

```
f[n_] := n^2 + n + 1
```

Becomes

```
f[n_] := 2n^3 + n^2 + n + 1
```

Note the `:=` syntax and the underscore.

If, instead, you want `f` to take the first definition for, say `n<=100` and the second for `n>100`, you would use the [Condition](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html) syntax `/;`, as shown below.

```
f[n_] := n^2 + n + 1 /; n<=100
f[n_] := 2n^3 + n^2 + n + 1 /; n>100
```

Answer (score 1):

This works, but requires separate functions.  Generalising the append function is not so easy.

```
Clear[f]
AppendToFunction := (
   a = DownValues[f];
   b = Append[a[[1, 2]], 2 n^3];
   f[n_] = Evaluate[b]);

AppendSinToFunction := (
   a = DownValues[f];
   b = Append[a[[1, 2]], Sin[n]];
   f[n_] = Evaluate[b]);

f[n_] := n^2 + n + 1;
f[3] == 9 + 4
DownValues[f]

(* 
->True
->{HoldPattern[f[n_]]:>n^2+n+1}
*)

AppendToFunction
f[3] == 9 + 4 + 54
DownValues[f]

(*
->1+n+n^2+2 n^3
->True
->{HoldPattern[f[n_]]:>1+n+n^2+2 n^3}
*)

AppendSinToFunction
f[3] == 9 + 4 + 54 + Sin[3]
DownValues[f]

(*
->1+n+n^2+2 n^3+Sin[n]
->True
->{HoldPattern[f[n_]]:>1+n+n^2+2 n^3+Sin[n]}
*)
```